# Is it 'bad practice' for an Angular controller to call a function on a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, controller, angularjs-directive

I have an Angular directive that implements what is essentially a custom combobox.  Clicking on the input control causes another div to appear below it and show a list of contained divs from a model object.  You can type text into the input control and it filters the list of divs below it.

I have a few separate button objects (not part of the directive, but in the same scope) that call methods like $scope.clearFilter() or $scope.unselectAll(), which, in turn, call directiveScope.clearFilter() or directiveScope.unselectAl().  directiveScope is a shared object between the combobox directive and the main controller.  It gives the controller the ability to call methods on the directive directly.

I put together a small [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8up0jx68mw8obNAl5Dsj?p=preview) showing how I am doing it currently.  This is an "in the spirit of" type of example, not my exact code (license issues).

```
// HTML
<my-directive sharedobj="myDirective1"></my-directive>
<input type="button" ng-click="clearFilterText1()" value="Clear"/><br/><br/>

// JS
var app = angular.module( 'Test', [] );

app.controller( 'MyController', [ '$scope', function( $scope ) {
  $scope.myDirective1 = {};
  $scope.myDirective2 = {};

  $scope.clearFilterText1 = function() {
    console.log("Calling directive 1");
    $scope.myDirective1.clearFilterText();
  }

  $scope.clearFilterText2 = function() {
    console.log("Calling directive 2");

    // QUESTION: If calling this directive method is bad practice, what is 
    //           equivalent good practice?
    $scope.myDirective2.clearFilterText();
  }
}]);

app.directive( 'myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: "<div><input type='text' ng-model='filterText'/></div>",
    scope: {
      sharedobj: "="
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    link: function( scope, elem, attrs ) {

      // This is the text that the directive will show, and it is conceptually private
      // to the directive, so I'd rather not put this into the controller scope.
      scope.filterText = "filter this!";

      // This method is on the "sharedobj" that is linked into the controller.
      // The controller is able to call this method directly, which updates
      // the view state.  This simply updates "view state".
      scope.sharedobj.clearFilterText = function() {
        console.log("Setting filter text!");
        scope.filterText = "";
      }

    }
  };
});
```

I've been told that having an Angular controller call a method on the directive directly is not good design, but according to [Wikipedia's page on MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

> A controller can send commands to the model to update the model's state (e.g.,
>   editing a document). **It can also send commands to its associated view**
>   to change the view's presentation of the model (e.g., by scrolling
>   through a document).

This sounds like exactly what I am doing if "send commands" is synonymous with "call functions", and if you consider a directive a "view", which I do, since directives are essentially extensions of HTML.

I've seen StackOverflow posts like [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510459/calling-a-directive-method-from-controller) that also suggest it's a bad idea (with no justification of that position), but the recommended alternative of implementing a separate service to handle this state seems like an unnecessarily complex solution, especially since I have multiple instances of these combobox directives.  You end up with a directive that doesn't even know its own view state, which just seems very wrong.

I don't see why calling SomeService.clearFilter(), which then sets some "state" that the directive has to $watch() for, is better than just calling someDirective.clearFilter() and avoiding all the overhead.  The controller still has to know about clearing the filter.  It just has to get injected with SomeService instead of being connected to the directive.

So, Angular/MVC experts, please tell me why this is wrong (or why it's okay)! :-)

Thanks.

Comment: MVC is a .. bucket term. Consider that Angular (as do KO and Kendo) work based on a declarative-observable model; which means that bucket-term statements need to be further applied in context.

Comment: In any case, instead of asking "Is it good/bad practice .." questions (and then defending them), simply ask about the given *task* outlining the situation - why the current approach is used and what the *issues/problems* associated with it are.

Comment: user2864740: The approach I have taken "works" just fine.  The "issues/problems" are coming from a code review where a co-worker feels the design would be better without controller-to-directive function calls and thinks it's "weird".  Also, any discussion of good/bad practice necessarily involves describing why one way is better than another (aka "defending" it), and there are usually tradeoffs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This article](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2014/02/11/lets-make-full-ass-angularjs-directives/), although it does not specifically address the "bad practice" question, does present a good way to organize the directive and controller, and just happens to be about a dropdown directive.

Answer (score 1):

Filters are a view concern.  I would inject them in the controller, but I wouldn't implement them inside of a service.

A service (which represents the Model) should not know anything about the view.

In your example, the view should call the controller, which then calls a scope method.  The scope method should define the filtering logic (which is what the controllers job is - to mediate the interaction between the view and the model (represented by services)).

This separation of concerns represents a layered design, where the responsibilities of the Model, the View, and the Controller are clearly defined.  There is a best practice, and that is to keep them separate.

In my opinion, having a filter defined inside of a service, which exposes a model, which is then watched by the scope is bad design.

Note: when I say filtering is a view concern, I mean angular filters - they are intended to work by keeping the filtered model and the view in sync, so I think of them as view concerns.

Comment: Actually the service doesn't necesary have to be the Model. In this video Mïsko explains that view logic should be at Controllers, but business logic should be at Services, which is actually one of the most common mistakes people make https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY

Comment: I use the term model loosely. It represents your business tier, so you and I are in agreement. The model is view agnostic, and not coupled to any controller.  Hence business services.

Comment: I was probably a bit unclear with my terms.  It's not a "filter" in the Angular sense.  It's the input text to the Angular filter that the directive uses.  There are other things too, like whether the combobox directive is open or closed.  The controller is also able to close the combobox directive if the user clicks somewhere outside the combobox (again by calling a method).

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to see this is that directives are thought to be either standalone or to add behaviour. When you call their functions through a controller you are actually making your directive depend on the existence of that controller, not being as reusable as it could/should be.

There are other ways to achieve the same result without coupling a viewController to a directive one, but it depends on each specific case so i cannot help you without more information :(

Cheers

Comment: The directive doesn't depend on the controller.  The controller uses a reference to the directive to change some presentation or view state in the directive via a method call.

Comment: If that method is only called via the controller then it does depend, as the directive by itself it's not enough to resolve everything

Comment: The easy way to see this is that if you want to create reusable and testable components, you should not execute directives functions from within a view controller

Comment: Sorry, but that is not how a dependency is defined.  Nobody would say that a directive "depends on" the thing that uses it.  Just as you wouldn't say that a ball depends on you to throw it.  Directives have no knowledge of the things using them.  The thing that uses a directive definitely depends on it though.  Also, the logic in your second comment is that the reason you shouldn't execute a directive from a controller is that "you should not execute directives from a controller".  Pretty circular, wouldn't you say?

Comment: If you must call a method on a directive from a view controller then your directive depends on that controller whether you like it or not. In order not to be a dependency, the method on that directive should trigger either by itself or through ui events.

In other words:
View Controller calling Directive method.
View calling Directive method = ok
Directive calling another directive's method = ok if they are dependant

Comment: There are some cases in which you want the directive to execute some code self contained and then trigger some other code from the view controller ON IT'S OWN SCOPE, that usually happens when you are developing a library module and need a callback for that directive's logic. In that case you could use the scope type "&" to pass a function that will execute NOT in the directive but in the controller. 

That way you can execute a function of the controller in the directive, and be able to pass parameters from the directive to the controller.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZGgNPTHc2Q

Comment: Sorry, but your idea of a 'dependency' is totally wrong.  The fact that there exists a method that a controller COULD call does not imply a dependency.  In this case, the directive DOES call happen the same method from an internal button click, but even if it didn't that still is not a dependency.  Saying that a function "depends on" someone to call it is just silly.  Regarding your reference to "&", that's all fine, but not relevant to my question.  I'm talking about a controller calling a directive, not a directive calling a controller.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Actually, what your code is doing, is making your directives define methods on an object from the controller. Although you argument that the methods are from the directive and are being called via controller, the methods are actually being created at the directive but are from the controller and being called by the controller. This is because all objects, functions and arrays in javascript work by reference except to the one that creates it (in this case the controller).

Comment: The easiest way to prove what i've just said is to bind a method to a controller scope and then do $scope = null or $scope = {}; By doing so you are destroying the reference to that object but not the object itself, which end up meaning that your view can still access the method you defined previous to destroy the $scope reference. No matter what i say, i won't be able to change your mind but i wanted to clarify for everyone else that there is and will be a dependency between the controller and directive whether you like it or not because the owner of myDirective1 and myDirective2 is the ctrl

Comment: To be clear, it's not that you can't change my mind, and I'm not trying to be a jerk, but you are simply wrong. Yes, there is a dependency "between" the controller and the directive, but that dependency has the controller depending on the directive, not the other way. The myDirective1 and myDirective2 are bound to the directive in the HTML, so the directive has no dependency on them.  You can replace the bindings with anything other object in any other controller and it will be okay. The fact that a directive requires you to use it in a certain way does NOT create a dependency on the user.

Comment: I maybe misunderstanding something, but I would ask a question: "Can the directive still serve the intended purpose if this controller is removed?". If the answer is "yes", then there is no dependency of the directive on this controller. Otherwise, there is.